# How to properly import custom font on all browsers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I have a custom font called `Roboto Condensed`.

I have placed all the fonts into a fonts folder.

I have a `eot`, `woff`, `woff2`, `ttf`, and `svg` all in here for cyrilica, greek, vietnamese, and latin along with extensions for greek, cyrillic and latin.

I am attempting to import it into my site like this:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic Ext.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}

/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Cyrillic.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek Ext.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Greek.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}


/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Vietnamese.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}


/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin Ext.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}


/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.eot");
  src:  url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.woff") format('woff'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("fonts/Roboto Condensed Latin.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

When I load the page and go to my developer tools I get two 404 errors, saying it can't find `.woff` and `.woff2` files. The files are there, spelled correctly, I triple checked before posting this.

Looking at the order, I am assuming chrome is loading `ttf` and ignoring other types because the custom font does load.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this maybe expected?

Comment: I have experienced this before with Chrome. Have you tried in other browsers? Might just be a weird Chrome thing and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, your code is correct, I am assuming you are under a IIS server, so you need to create those 2 missing mime-types.

You can create either in:

- [IIS7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Plesk](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/plesk/add-mime-type-to-domain-plesk/) - (If this is your Admin Domain panel)
- [Web.Config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config)

So a standard `Web.config` for both mime-types would be something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
     <!-- remove first in case they are defined in IIS already, which would cause a runtime error -->
     <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am under IIS Server, can you tell me how to create those 2 mimetypes?

Comment: If I run the following command: `appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension=' string ',mimeType=' string ']"` then fileExtension would be .woff2 and mimeType would be what?

Comment: `fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2"`

Comment: ok and for woff it would be the same?  I've read somewhere that iis8 and up already support woff, yet my browser complained about that too.

Comment: yup would be the same