# Custom Font is not supporting in all browser

Tags: css, fonts

Custom font is not supporting in any browser. Here is my code for declaring and accessing the fonts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Graphik-regular';
    src: url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.eot');
    src: url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Graphik-medium';
    src: url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium.eot');
    src: url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
        url('192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060612/how-to-properly-import-custom-font-on-all-browsers

Comment: When I paste _192.168.1.11/assets/fonts/Graphik/Graphik-Regular.woff_ into my browser, I get a timeout error. Or wait, is this a subdirectory named "192.168.1.11"?

Comment: yes that is calling using subdirectory